# What is the variance of a constant and set rate?

Tags: variance, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

Say we have two options:

1. out of every 25 videos, one will be promoted
2. every video has a 4% chance of being promoted

For the first example, it's meant that after 25 videos, it's guaranteed that exactly one will be promoted.

How would we calculate the expectation and variance for 1000 videos shown?

For me it seems like:

1.

> $E(promoted|1000 ads) = 1000 \cdot 0.04 = 40$
> $Var(promoted|1000 ads) = 0$ # because the number cannot vary

2. 

> $E(promoted|1000 ads) = 1000 \cdot 0.04 = 40$
> $Var(promoted|1000 ads) = 0.04(0.96) $ # because the number of promotions follows a bernoulli distribution and so does the variance.

Does this seem right?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen This isn't from a course; I'm just trying to learn this for my statistical understanding.